# How to Overcome from this 0 objc_msgSend

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, exception

[image: When i 'm click buttons randomly it gets like this without any error , how to resolve it please suggest me and how to overcome from this type of errors]

When i'm click buttons randomly in application it gets like this without any error or any Exception
please suggest me and how to overcome from this type of errors

thanks in advance

Comment: Its looks like your object is deallocated and you are trying to access it. Enable `NSZombieEnabled` It helps you to identify which object is released.

Comment: Must be that tricky 'main' function... best to remove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint for all the exceptions in your code, there's nothing we can do with that information.

[image]

If that doesn't help, just profile your app with instruments.

Comment: This does not help in this case. There are no exceptions involved.